# Replacing a values in a given column at a given row by values located at other rows

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing

I have the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'a': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]})
```

I would like to create a loop that:

1. counts the number of consecutive 1s in df['a']and;
2. assigns that number as value in df['b'] at the row of the first 1 of the sequence.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting here the solution to my question. Any improvement is welcomed!

```
df['b'] = np.NaN
count = 0

for i in df.index:
  if df.loc[i,'a'] == 1:
    count += 1
  else:
    j = i - count
    df.loc[j,'b'] = count
    count = 0
```

This code yields to:

```
print(df['b'].values)

>>> [ 0.  0.  1. nan  6. nan nan nan nan nan nan  0.  0.  0.  0.  2. nan nan
 11. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
```

Which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

What about first creating a df.temp_index,
Loop through the row, set temp_index to be 1 (for that row) when df.consecutive has value 1. Then increment this until you hit df.consecutive being 1.

Then look up each row where df.temp_index being one as well as the row before it. The row before it contains the total number of rows between previous one and the next one. You can then copy this number of row value to a new column.

As to is there a quick trick to do these steps in pandas, I don’t know at top of my head, at least not all steps. Try implement the above steps either looping through or pandas trick and see how far you get.

Comment: What have you tried? There is a direct loop way of doing this but there’s some quick pandas 1-2 liners if that’s what you are after..,

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'obs': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
'A': [4, 1, 1, 7, 1],
})

df['B']=df.obs[df.A.eq(1)].reindex(df.index).fillna(0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   obs  A    B
0    1  4  0.0
1    2  1  2.0
2    3  1  3.0
3    4  7  0.0
4    5  1  5.0
```

---

If `df.obs` is the index, you could try:

```
df['b']=df.index.where(df.A.eq(1)).fillna(0)
#same as: df['b']=np.where(df.A.eq(1), df.index, 0)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it will change a little bit, just edited the answer in that case. @nalfahel